# Django Model form does not display when I include it in the Parent template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Long story short , My form.html Only shows submit button rather than all the fields of the model form

```
  <div class="form">
    <form action="{% url 'name' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <p style="color: red;">Watch it before it gets removed on The Internet</p>
  </div>
```

Here is forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import ModelForm 
from .models import Person

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name','email']
```

when I tried adding html inputs manually on forms.html I was able to make the inputs show on the page , Is something wrong with importing model form like that ??

Also what's weird is that when I click on that submit button since its the only one showing on the page … It takes me to a plain form.html with validation error , since I was submitting empty values

Here is how I include it in the Parent template `{% include "form.html" %}`

Comment: add your views.py

Comment: in the mean time try this {{ form.as_p }}

Comment: Hello @OmegaJoctan can you provide views.py or provide function which is responsible to handle your form.

Answer (score 0):

This is my view for that form

```
def get_name(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
       form = PersonForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()           
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thank-you')) 

    else: 
        form = PersonForm()

    return render(request,'form.html',{ 'form': form })
```

It works well when I don't just include in other template when it is all alone